# How to know which resource is throwing a HttpException in my Application_Error

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

The Application_Error event is being raised in my application with a HttpException. Inside the exception I see a 404 error code - resource not found.

I've already used Firebug to check if there's some image/css/js with 404 error code and didn't found.

The question is: How can I get the resource that's firing this error?

Thanks,

Armando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking `Request.Url` in `Application_Error` in `Global.asax`.

Comment: I agree with rsbarro. Additionally, _sender_ object/parameter of **Application_Error** is worth checking.

Comment: @iturman: It appears that the `sender` just contains a reference to Global.asax. In other words, within the `Application_Error` method in Global.asax `sender == this` evaluates to `true`.